# Reading files from a private s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My application has an internal messaging service, which allows users to send images, these images are saved in my bucket and the URL saved in my database.
Previously my bucket was configured to have public access and the images were accessible within my application through the URL, but following the AWS recommendations I would like to change the settings and block all public access, therefore I would like to know what would be the best alternative for users within my application to have access to the images.

I have evaluated the option of using pre-signed URLs, but then every time a user wants to access an image my application would have to create a new temporary URL and update the record in my database? Wouldn't this be an overload of resources?

Comment: Could you sign an URL whenever a user wants to access an image, send that signed URL to the user for them to use, and not store the signed URL anywhere?

Comment: For buckets of assets that you want actually public, a good approach is to use cloudfront with origin access control so that the bucket itself can remain private. I would only use pre-signed urls if you have authorization to control which users can access which assets.

Comment: Rather than save the URL in your database, save the S3 object key and the S3 bucket name. No, you don't have to store pre-signed URLs in your database and, in fact, you should not because they're time-limited. Just create them as needed in your app server.

Comment: @jarmod. Based on my old application logic, saving the URL of a file within a publicly accessible bucket seemed practical. However, your approach now seems more reasonable. I think I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two options:

#### Use public objects

I presume that you want specific users to be able to view images, but you don't want the objects totally accessible to everyone on the Internet. One option you could use is a complex filename (Key) for the objects, make the bucket (or the objects) 'public' and prohibit people from listing the contents of the bucket. Thus, if somebody knows the URL to the object then they can access the object, but they are unlikely to find objects by chance.

This is [Security through obscurity - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) but that might be acceptable given your type of data -- this is your choice to make.

#### Use pre-signed URLs

If you want to ensure that only authorized people will be able to access the objects, then you need all requests to be sent to a back-end that will:

- Confirm that the user is entitled to access the object
- Generate a pre-signed URL and return it to the user

However, I suspect that most of the times that the user requests access to the object they won't be "logged-in", so this is going to a lot of effort for no benefit. To explain, if a request is sent to the back-end and a pre-signed URL is returned *without* authenticating the user, then it is not much better than simply using a public object with an obfuscated URL.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. As for the requests for access to the objects, these will always be made from an authenticated user, so I don't think there is a problem on that side.